# Entity Framework Code First - Database schema that changes too often

Tags: c#, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6

Im looking for an advice. I plan to use EntityFramework Code First. I am developing a system where entities into EF model can be added from external modules. What are the best practices of doing this ? The database model should be changed at runtime.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is a code first issue. Basically you are trying to execute DDL (create table, update table etc.) commands against a database from the application itself. My suggestion is that you run your application against a database (say, AppMasterDb) which users cannot change. If they want to inject table or views, allocate them a different database or schema for logical separation.